# Mobius strip/band

Tags: general-topology, mobius-transformation, mobius-band

What happens when we cut Mobius band at "2/3" of its height? Will we get two pieces which are tangled and one shorter than other?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You should make a paper model and try it out yourself! :)

Comment: I got two pieces tangled with each other one shorter than other . Shorter one has 1 turn and the bigger one had 4 :D

Comment: If we are just given Mobius band, should we assume automatically that it has one twist/turn?

Comment: The standard Möbius band has one half-twist, but any odd number of half twists will give you something homeomorphic to the Möbius band, but embedded in space differently.